# GWT: Log4j Issue

Tags: java, gwt, log4j

I have been battling with this issue now for over 48 hours. So I have a gwt app that I developed, I then decided to add persistence to it by using GAE datastore (Entities), everything worked well, so I decided to use JPA to reduce the amount of code I wrote using Entities.

I ran into issues with datanucleus, a lot!! until I could not even get my app to start up any more. I have tried a whole lot new configs and now I am caught between a rock and a hard place.

I bumped into this [pom](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/expenses/pom.xml) so I decided to use, I removed things I do not need because they were breaking at compile time.

At the moment. I can compile and run without issues but when request goes through GWT, I get this weird exception

```
2012-04-30 14:02:45.175:WARN::Error for /LottoShop/lottoService
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: |?The import org.apache.log4j cannot be resolved|
        at co.za.cre8.web.lottoShop.server.LottoServiceImpl.<init>(LottoServiceImpl.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at co.za.cre8.web.lottoShop.server.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:49)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
2012-04-30 14:02:45.195:WARN::Error for /LottoShop/lottoService
```

I **do not** have a single import of `import org.apache.log4j` infact there is none in that Class LottoService.

This is how my dependecy tree looks like:

```
[INFO] Building GWT Maven Archetype
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] co.za.cre8.web:lottoShop:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge:rsslib4j:jar:0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.allen-sauer.gwt.log:gwt-log:jar:3.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-jpa:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-rdbms:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:transaction-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-eb:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.el:el-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
```

Even when I use slf4j by removing log4j in my dependency, I added the below: Nothing works , same issue, When I look in Eclipse mvn dependencies, the log library is there and even in

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10</version>
</dependency>                
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Added a proof that slf4j is in WEB-INF/lib

[image: WEB-INF lib Folder]

Your assistance will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you tried a good Clean in Eclipse (clean both target/classes and then webapp/WEB-INF/classes too )and then recompile everything? Does Eclipse show any error when compiling from scratch? To me it looks like an old clumsy class has been left by Eclipse compiler. Unresolved compilation error are usually caused by that

Comment: Hi @GuillaumePolet , I do the clean every now and then, comes in handy, this is not the case. No resolve warnings in eclipse, everything looks fine. What is still a misery to me is, I do not have that  import org.apache.log4j 

 at co.za.cre8.web.lottoShop.server.LottoServiceImpl.<init>(LottoServiceImpl.java:11)

Comment: Did you clean the Webapp/WEB-INF/classes directory manually? I don't think Eclipse does it when you call clean (although I am not completely sure)

Answer (score 0):

did you add log4j in your classpath? Slf4j is just a Facde interface, from the jar files that you used, Slf4j need find log4j to generate the log infomation.

Comment: Actually, he could use other logging frameworks if he wanted to (like logback which is supposed to be the next log4j). But from the screenshot he's showing and the dependency-tree exposed above, looks like log4j is on the classpath (see the jar log4j-1.2.16.jar).

Comment: I could use logback but what are the chances it will work, because that import is been used somewhere which I cannot see, could it have been a 3rd party libary ? Do 3rd parties ship libs with logging ?

Comment: yes, there are some thrid party libs using logging framework. So you need beware about it.